# jQuery display table from database dynamically with select

Tags: php, jquery, database, post

This code should display every time some data from my database when i change the option.

> Select  button

```
<head>    
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>


    <select id="seira" class="seira">
        <option value="ola">ΣΕΙΡΑ</option>
        <option value="S 67">S 67</option>    
        <option value="M 9660">M 9660</option>
        <option value="M 11000">M 11000</option>
        <option value="M 20000">M 20000</option>
        <option value="M 9400">M 9400</option>
        <option value="S 560">S 560</option>
        <option value="S 350">S 350</option>
        <option value="M 14600">M 14600</option>
        <option value="M 9200">M 9200</option>
        <option value="ΣΗΤΕΣ">ΣΗΤΕΣ</option>
        <option value="ΓΑΛΟΝΑΚΙΑ">ΓΑΛΟΝΑΚΙΑ</option>
        <option value="ΠΗΧΑΚΙΑ">ΠΗΧΑΚΙΑ</option>
        <option value="ΑΡΜΟΚΑΛΥΠΤΡΑ">ΑΡΜΟΚΑΛΥΠΤΡΑ</option>
        <option value="ΡΑΜΠΟΤΕ">ΡΑΜΠΟΤΕ</option>
    </select>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.seira').change(function(){
        var seira = $("#seira").val();
        $.post("display_seira.php", 
                {
                     seira : seira
                },function(data){

                    $("#display").html(data);

                });

    });
});
</script>
```

> Table's header and below i want to display my database

```
<table>  
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Περιγραφή</th>
                <th>Kατασκευαστής</th>
                <th><?php include_once 'select_seira.php' ?></th>
                <th>Χρώμα</th>
                <th>Μήκος</th>
                <th>Ποσότητα</th>
                <th>Τοποθεσία</th>    
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <p id="display"></p>          

    </table>
```

> IF  the 1st value  is selected then i want to display all my database , else i want to display the "seira" that i choose.

```
<?php
include_once 'database/database_connection.php';
$seira = $_POST['seira'];
?>


<?php  
 if ($seira = 'ola') {  ?>
    <tbody>         
    <?php

           $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_alumil;";
           $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
           $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
           if ($resultCheck > 0) {
               while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                   ?>
<tr id="row"  ?>
   <td style="font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 2px;"><?php echo $row['id']; ?>
   <input type="hidden" name='id' value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
   <td style="font-style: italic;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
   <td style="font-style: oblique;"><?php echo $row['buyer']; ?></td>
   <td style="font-style: italic;"><?php echo $row['seira']; ?></td>          
   <td><?php echo $row['color']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['length']; 
   echo " (mm)";?></td>
   <td id="value10" style="font-weight: bold; background:<?= ($row['value'] >= 10 ? 'rgb(132, 247, 132)' : ($row['value'] >= 5? 'orange' : 'rgb(247, 132, 132)'));?>"><?php echo $row['value'];?>
   <input type="hidden" name='value' value="<?php echo $row['value']; ?>"></td> 


   <td><?php echo $row['place'];?></td>  


</tr>


       <?php
           }    
       }

       ?>

</tbody>
<?php }else {?>
    <tbody>         
                    <?php
                        $i = 0;
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `stock_alumil` WHERE `seira`='$seira';";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
                        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                            while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                ?>
            <tr id="row"  ?>
                <td style="font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 2px;"><?php echo $row['id']; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name='id' value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
                <td style="font-style: italic;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td style="font-style: oblique;"><?php echo $row['buyer']; ?></td>
                <td style="font-style: italic;"><?php echo $row['seira']; ?></td>          
                <td><?php echo $row['color']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['length']; 
                echo " (mm)";?></td>
                <td id="value10" style="font-weight: bold; background:<?= ($row['value'] >= 10 ? 'rgb(132, 247, 132)' : ($row['value'] >= 5? 'orange' : 'rgb(247, 132, 132)'));?>"><?php echo $row['value'];?>
                <input type="hidden" name='value' value="<?php echo $row['value']; ?>"></td> 


                <td><?php echo $row['place'];?></td>   


            </tr>


                    <?php
                        }    
                    }

                    ?>

        </tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried  it , but it displaysonly the first value that i choose , and when i want to change my select value, it doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: `if ($seira = 'ola')` Are you sure this line is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hi  guys , i find the answer for my code. I post it below if anyone want to check it.*

> New jQuery Code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.seira').change(function(){       
        $("select option:selected").each(function(){
            $("#display_full").hide();
            var seira = $(this).val();
            $.post("display_seira.php", 
                {
                     seira : seira
                },function(data){    
                    $("#display").html(data);  
                });
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Now  everytime that  i am change my select-option one new table is displayed automatically , without refreshing the page.